# Redirecting ruby Curses to /dev/null

Tags: ruby, rspec, curses

I'm trying to write specs for an app that uses Ruby's Curses library. Curses obviously monopolizes the terminal screen, so I've tried redirecting rspec's output to a file. This works, for the most part, but some of my failing specs are missing information, and I think RSpec is printing some of its output to $stdout.

I've tried configuring the Curses library to not print to the screen, but to no avail. Is there any way to disable Curses output so that tests can be run normally?

Answer (score 0):

Try [`Curses.close_screen`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/curses/rdoc/Curses.html#method-c-close_screen), when you decide to resume output of Curses, call `Curses.refresh`

Comment: Tried that, and it does help, although the rspec formatting is all off. Any idea on how to reset that? It seems like linebreaks aren't being respected.

Answer (score 0):

I have a configuration flag that specifies whether or not to do the curses output.  For unit tests, I disable curses output.

In addition, at runtime I test to see if stdout and stderr are tty's; if not, they're redirected to files and I don't want curses output.  It looks something like this:

```
  def do_curses_output?
    $stdin.isatty && $stdout.isatty && want_curses_output
  end

  def foo
    if do_curses_output?
      # ... do the curses stuff
    end
  end
```

-- Keith